# How to do proper error handling in javascript?

Tags: javascript, callback, try-catch

I have three functions, each of them calling another function.

```
function one() {
   two();
}

function two() {
   three();
}

function three() {
   // here an error will occur, and then should be resolved
   try {
      // whatever
   } catch (e) {
      // here should the error be resolved;
   }

}
```

Now my question is, how do I achieve that when calling one(), the error that will occur in three() will be handed to function two() and then to function one() which then does something with the error ONLY ths function can. I tried it with callbacks but that didnt work and with try/catch, but as Im new to all that error resolving stuff I probably messed something up. Here my attempts for callback and try catch:

```
function one() {
   try {
     two();
   } catch (e) {
     console.log(e);
   }
}

function two() {
  try {
   three();
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
}

function three() {
   // here an error will occur, and then should be resolved
   try {
      // whatever
   } catch (e) {
      return new Error("ERROR");
   }

}
```

Callbacks:

```
function one(function (err) {
  if (err == "ERROR") { 
       console.log("everything worked");
  } else { throw err }
});



function two(callback) {
  try {
     three(callback);
  } catch (e) {
     return callback(e);
  }

 function three(callback) {
     try {
        //whatever
    } catch (e) {
      return callback(new Error("ERROR");
    }
  }
```

---

Maybe I should explain what I am working on. I have a function that reads data from a file by its filename and then returns the data. ANother function recieves that data and manipulates it, but I am only focussing on the recieving. That also has the parameter path. Basically, its looking like this:

```
function main() {
  try {
manipulateData("C:\\......");//That file doesnt exist, so an error will occur
   } catch (e) {
      return console.log("Error": e);
   }
}

function manipulateData(path) {
    var data = getUserdata(path);
    .....
}

function getUserdata(path) {
    return fs.readFileSync(path);
}
```

Comment: `try { two(); } catch (e) { ... }` in `one`, and simply `throw new Error` in `three`…? `two` doesn't need to do anything special.

Comment: The comments in `three` in your first code block make me wonder: Are you looking to have `one` handle the error and then let `three` continue? If so, you can't do that in JavaScript (yet, there's talk of adding something that would let you, but it's not even on the proposal track yet). Instead, split up `three` into two separate functions and have the first part of `three` call the new function with the second part of `three`, and have `one `also call that new function when dealing with the error. Although this interconnectedness makes me wonder if a more through refactor is needed.

Comment: @deceze Tried it, but then the program logs Error: ERROR at three and then exits. But I want the error the be caused or thrown by one

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I meant, that it is sure that in function three an error will occur. And what I want to achieve is that the error caused in function three will be passed through function two into one, where I then check if the errors message is ERROR and go on.

Comment: Then `throw new Error` from `one`'s `catch` block, if you want the error to appear to originate in `one`?

Comment: @NicolasStadler - What do you mean by "and go on"? "Go on" in **`one`** or "go on" in **`three`**?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in one.

Comment: @deceze I dont want to throw the error. I want to get the error caused in three in function one so I can go on with the error from three in one without throwing anything. I dont want to throw an error, because my program then stops.

Comment: Whenever I do try {one()} catch {...}, the program stops at one() and I cant even get to resolving the error, because my program stops before the catch part.

Comment: @NicolasStadler Yes you *do* want to `throw` the error. No, the program doesn't stop before going into the `catch`. Is the error actually thrown synchronously from within the `try` block? Please show us the actual code that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle the error in `one`, you use a `try`/`catch` in `one`:

```js
function one() {
    console.log(`in one`);
    try {
        two();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`handling error "${e.message}...`);
        console.log("continuing work...");
    }
}

function two() {
    console.log(`in two`);
    three();
}

function three() {
    console.log(`in three`);
    // Error is caused here:
    null.example();
}

one();
```